# User defined module cannot find top level variables and modules

Tags: python, module, scope

I have a user defined module (called test.py) as such:

```
def getLastDate(currDt):
    prevDt = (currDt - dt.timedelta(days=1))
    return prevDt
```

I am trying to call it from another python script:

```
import datetime as dt
import test
currDt = dt.date.today()
print(test.getLastDate(currDt))
```

The problem is that when I run it, the scope of this is such that the inner module (test.py) is unable to find the dt module and gives the following error:

```
      1 def getLastDate(currDt):
----> 2     prevDt = (currDt - dt.timedelta(days=1))
      3     return prevDt

NameError: name 'dt' is not defined
```

Do I have to reload datetime module inside my test.py module? This does not seem right to me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as it's written you'll need to import datetime in test.py.

If you want to avoid importing datetime twice you could just import it in test.py and rewrite your function like:

```
def getLastDate(currDt, delta):
    prevDt = (currDt - dt.timedelta(days=delta))
    return prevDt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import dt also in test.py file

```
#test.py
import datetime as dt
def getLastDate(currDt):
    prevDt = (currDt - dt.timedelta(days=1))
    return prevDt
```